# How to get all parents that children all match attribute?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this parent table

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

and this children table

| id | parent_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

I want to query the tables(using laravel elloquent) and get the parents that have all their children match status 3. For example here id = 2 in parent table matches this criteria

Comment: Why you have children table with duplicate ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to test it, but this may work:

```php
Parent::whereDoesntHave('children', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', '!=', 3);
})->whereHas('children')
```

The resulting SQL looks like this:

```sql
select 
  * 
from 
  `parents` 
where 
  not exists (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `children` 
    where 
      `parents`.`id` = `children`.`parent_id` 
      and `status` != 3
  ) 
  and exists (
    select 
      * 
    from 
      `children` 
    where 
      `parents`.`id` = `children`.`parent_id`
  )
```

It selects only parents that have children and excludes the ones that has children with a status not equal to 3

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution can be slow on huge datasets with several millions of rows in each table.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is one option:

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN children c
    ON c.parent_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING MIN(c.status) = MAX(c.status) AND MIN(c.status) = 3;
```